# Access 2D Vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, 2d

I want to access a variable of an Object, by using a pointer, which is inside a 2d vector.
Here is the code:

```
class Soldier{
public:
    Soldier(char c){
        type = c;
    }
    char type;
};

int main()
{
//initialising the 2d vector (should give me an empty 2*3 vector)
    vector< vector<Soldier> > *armys = new vector< vector<Soldier> >(2, vector<Soldier>(3));
//fill each of the vector
    Soldier a('x');
    (*armys)[0].push_back(a);
    (*armys)[0].push_back(a);
    (*armys)[0].push_back(a);
    Soldier b('x');
    (*armys).resize(2);
    (*armys)[1].push_back(b);
    (*armys)[1].push_back(b);
    (*armys)[1].push_back(b);

    for (int army = 0; army < (*armys).size(); army++){
        for (int soldier = 0; soldier < (*armys)[army].size(); soldier++){
            cout << (*armys)[army][soldier].type;
        }cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Sadly this won't compile.

What i want to have is just:
Pointer --> (Army1, Army2, Army3 , ...) each of them --> (Soldier of some type)

Can someone give me a hint or tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: "... a pointer, which is inside a 2d vector" The 2d vector doesn't contain pointers.

Comment: Why using `std::vector<..>*` and not just `std::vector`?

Comment: `vector<Soldier>(3)` requires a default constructor. Note that if you're going to use `push_back`, you shouldn't pre-size the vector — you'd end up with six elements in each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2nd version of the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of your inner vector called here: `vector<Soldier>(3)` requires a default constructor for `Soldier` to be defined, because the value parameter is defaulted to default-constructed value.

Since you've provided constructor taking `char`, the default one is not generated. So do either one:

- define default constructor i. e. `Soldier() : type('x') {}` or add
  a default value for the parameter: `Soldier(char c = 'x') : type(c) {}`
- construct the inner vector with again, defaulted `Soldier`s : `vector<Soldier>(3, Soldier('x'))`

The code will compile now. But your `armys` initialization doesn't make sense to me. As mentioned in comments, the pointer here surely does not make any vector contain `Soldier*` elements and only causes memory leak since you forgot to delete it. Besides that, do you really need `armys` to be filled with initial values?

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i wanted to know. It seems i got too dizzy with all the code around and pointer stuff since i am pretty new to it, that i couldn't figure it our on my own. But thanks now its working!

Comment: @RIJIK Be a fair user and accept the answer then. Do it for your other questions too.

Comment: @RIJIK Just click on the gray check next to the answer and it goes green. You should have visited http://stackoverflow.com/tour as the first thing after registering.

Comment: @RIJIK You need 15 reputation to upvote, the "accept this answer as correct" check is below.

Comment: ahh i got it! ^^ i somehow didn#t see it